# External hard drive spinning up during sleep

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake, external-disk

Every time I close the lid on my macbook air, my external hard drive seems to spin up for about 5 seconds every 30 seconds, and this will go on continuously, even for several hours. The noise itself isn't too loud, so I don't really have a problem with that, but I'm worried it might damage the hard drive.

Is this normal OS X behaviour (I'm on Mountain Lion, sleep mode 3), or is it specific to my model of hard drive ([Samsung 1tb USB 3](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Samsung-Slimline-Portable-Hard-Drive/dp/B008PABFX8))? I read that Mountain Lion will supposedly check emails and perform updates during sleep, could that be the cause?

If it doesn't harm the hard drive, I'm not too worried, but if repeated spinning up will exert extra strain, I'd like to find a way to stop this happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Mac OS doesn't eject hard drives when the machine enters sleep. And since your MacBook performs some "activity" during sleep, a writing/reading process might keep the hard disks awake.

There are at least three solutions to this problem:

A) You eject the hard disks each time before you enter sleep

B) You get the Jettison App for $4.95 (http://www.stclairsoft.com/Jettison/), which automatically ejects hard disks before the MacBook enters sleep, and mounts them when the MacBook awakes. There is a 15 days free trial if you like to check if it works for you.
[image]

C) Disable the Power Nap mode

Comment: For anyone coming across this and trying to disable power nap mode, make sure to check both the battery _and_ the power adapter tabs in Energy Saver, as the mode needs to be disabled in both of these sections to prevent the effect.

Comment: So, which solution did you end up with?

Comment: I went for C. I didn't want to have to remount my hard drive each time I woke my laptop, and I wasn't looking to spend any money, but I might get that app at some point anyway as it sounds quite useful for when you need to unplug it during sleep.

Comment: I have a MacBook Mid 2010, so there is no power nap I had to bother with. But I have 3 HDs hooked up to it via USB-HUB, and ejected them separately each time when I had to take my laptop with me. But fortunately I discovered Jettison recently, which does no magic, but makes life a little bit easier.

Comment: Does it ever fail to eject a hard drive, such as when some applications keep a lock on the hard drive, preventing the drive from being unmounted?

Comment: Yes, it does. I had such a case once with iTunes. Bascically, all what the program does is to attempt to unmount the disks as you would do it manually by dragging them into "Trash", and it re-mounts them automatically when the computer awakes. There are several options accessible from the menu bar, I add them as a screenshot to my answer

Comment: I think they offer a 15 day trial version. you can just try and see if it works for you

Comment: Ok, so as long as I remember to quit any such applications it should work fine.. Yeah I will try it, I think this might be very useful for me, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Try with disabled Power Nap mode!

In system preferences energy saver.

Here is my setting, but I do not have an external HD to check that.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have solved my problem :). I only accepted the other solution because it was more informative and gave an explanation of why it happens.

Comment: Great answer. It would be nice if one could only disable calendar and email updates, I wouldn't mind if it makes a Time Machine backup when it's due.